# Blank screen after logging in with password

Tags: 12.04, upgrade

I completed an upgrade from Ubuntu 11.04 to 14.04 LTS.  After the upgrade finished it seems like everything was working.  Then I turned the computer off over night and the next day the machine powers up, I get the logon screen and I put in my password, and then I get a blank screen.  I am running on a Dell inspiron 531, using the 64 bit ubuntu.  Is there any way to get around this?  I do have the nvidia driver installed.  I also noticed that on the blue screen during booting that it showed Kubuntu 11.10, but then the login screen noted Ubuntu  12.04 LTS.  When it rebooted after the update I did notice two program failures: 1. compiz closed unexpectedly, 2. ITalc also closed unexpectedly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. install gdm from tty1 (ctrl+alt+F1), 
   #apt-get install gdm
2. #dpkg-reconfigure lightdm

change the default display manager from lightdm  to gdm

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
1. #startx
2. Backup all important info
3. Format HDD.

I proved all the solutions that I found in Internet and none worked for me...